# Counting and compare

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So, I'm working on a project for Warhammer40k fans. I must block registrations for a tournament if enough members of the same team are already registered.
eg: a 3v3 tournament, I have to block if a fourth of any team want to subscribe.

So I have to compare all the `team.name` of the connected user with all the `team.name` of all participants and block if those users' `team.name` appeared 3 times already.

At the begginning I did this:

```
checkTeamsMember(){
    let teamNumberCheck: number = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.myTeams.length; i++){
      for (let j = 0; j < this.teams.length; j++){
        if (this.teams[j].team_name == this.myTeams[i].name){
          teamNumberCheck ++
        }
      }
    }
    if (teamNumberCheck == this.tournamentToShow.team_length){
      this.activateButton = !this.activateButton;
    }
  }
```

But it is not the solution since you can be a member of multiple teams.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems like `this.myTeams` is an array with all the teams the active user is in, but what does `this.teams` represent? Is it a flat list of all the teams of all the registered members ?

Comment: Give us the sample set of team names for each array.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer.

Sorry for the lack of explain, this.myTeams is an array with all the teams the active user is in and this.teams represent an array with all team_name of the participants.

So it can be :

```
let myTeams = ["hello world", "Testers"]
let teams = ["Orks", "hello world", "hello world", "Orks", "Testers"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your code is tracking the number of overlaps for *all* teams, but what you need is to track the number of overlaps for *each* team:

```
checkTeamsMember(){
    let playerCanRegister: boolean = true; // whether all the user's teams have an open slot

    for (let i = 0; i < this.myTeams.length; i++){
      let teamNumberCheck: number = 0; // current # registered from team this.myTeams[i]

      for (let j = 0; j < this.teams.length; j++){
        if (this.teams[j].team_name == this.myTeams[i].name){
          teamNumberCheck ++
        }
      }

      let isTeamSpotOpen = (teamNumberCheck < this.tournamentToShow.team_length);
      playerCanRegister = playerCanRegister && isTeamSpotOpen; // if any team is closed, player cannot register
    }

    if (!playerCanRegister){
      this.activateButton = !this.activateButton;
    }
  }
```

There are other ways that this could be made more efficient (e.g. ending the loop as soon as you discover a team has reached max registration).

Comment: Thanks, I modify a bit your code and it works, you helped me a lot !